# What tags does Google NL API use in its annotate syntax response?

Tags: part-of-speech, google-cloud-nl, brat

I am using Google NL API's annotate syntax method and using Brat to visualize the response. Where can I find the exact list of "Tags" or "Labels" for words and dependency relations that are used in Google NL API.

"partOfSpeech": {
    "tag": "ADJ",

"dependencyEdge": {
    "headTokenIndex": 9,
    "label": "AMOD"

Comment: Full list of tags is here: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/Token#PartOfSpeech and dependency labels are here: https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/Token#DependencyEdge

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot Sara